# How to get the standardized z-statistic from dunn.test-package in R?

Tags: interpretation, kruskal-wallis-test, bonferroni, reporting, dunn-test

Sorry if this is a trivial question, but I couldn't find anything on it.

I am running a Dunn-test with the dunn.test-package:

`dunn.test(data$climatescepticism, g = data$mediaoutlet, method = "bonferroni")`

I get the following output:

```
data: x and group
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 28.2413, df = 3, p-value = 0


                         Comparison of x by group                            
                                 (Bonferroni)                                  
Col Mean-|
Row Mean |          1          2          3
---------+---------------------------------
       2 |   4.638266
         |    0.0000*
         |
       3 |   0.166923  -4.445118
         |     1.0000    0.0000*
         |
       4 |   2.842656  -2.566897   2.592805
         |    0.0134*     0.0308     0.0286
```

To report this results in my thesis I need the standardized test statistic.

Is the Z statistic in this output already standardized? And if not, how is it possible to obtain the standardized value or at least get the standard error to calculate it myself?

Comment: "Sorry if this is a trivial question, but I couldn't find anything on it." Perhaps try e-mailing the author at the supplied address in the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

The $z$ test statistics are reported in the output of `dunn.test`, as you can see in your supplied output (e.g., `4.638266` is the $z$ statistic, and the starred `0.0000` beneath it  is the $p$ value). **Aside:** *all* $z$ statistics are ‘standardized’ in that they derive from the [standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Definitions).

If your use the `list=TRUE` option, you will get the same numbers ($z$ statistics and $p$ values) arranged in list form also.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get the z-score, try installing the package "FSA" instead. See the image of the code below. Cheers.

[image]

Comment: –1 dunnTest in the FSA package is just a "rewrapping" of my dunn.test package and offers no additional functionality.